# how to print multiple sizes in one page with css?

Tags: html, css, web, printing

is possible to print a web page into multiple pages(print) with different sizes(portrait or landscape).

example : I have one web page which displays contents which will be break into  several pages for printing, the first 2 part of contents will be printed in portrait and the others will be printed in landscape.

tell me guys, it is possible ?

I never used css for printing before.

Comment: did you try out setting print area & print area sizes in css ?

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: I did not try that, I never used css for printing, so this is my first time deal with printing in css

Comment: yes you set printable area using css.give id to printable  div area & set size for that using css